# The type 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector3' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, monogame

I try to add accelerator movement to my Windows Phone Monogame application and this is what happens

> Error  3
>   The type 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector3' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=842cf8be1de50553'.
>
> Error  2   Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector3' to 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector3

Here is the line

```
private void UpdateUI(AccelerometerReading accelerometerReading)
{ 
    Vector3 acceleration = accelerometerReading.Acceleration; 
}
```

I added the Monogame.Framework.WindowsPhone project, which includes class Vector3, doesnt work.
I added the assembly Microsoft.Xna.Framework, shows the yellow triangle and a warning that

> "Warning   5   The referenced component 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework' could not be found. "

The error was reported on MSDN site and no one responded. I found a smiliar problem, bo their solution doesnt work for me.

Im 12 hours into this and still nothing. I dropped the Unity, I dropped the Cocos2d, I dropped the XNA, becouse of 1231231 errors reported by Visual Studio.
Please help me Obi Wan Kenobi, you're my only hope.

Comment: Instead of reporting the error on the MSDN, you should do so on the Monogame forums as it is more likely to be on their side than Microsofts. Maybe a bug or not yet supported feature in Monogame?

Answer (score 0):

I've the same issue here. As a workaround, I've moved the accelerometer logic to a Project without Monogame references and all is working properly with this solution.

For instance, you can have something like:

```
public class Utils
{
    public static void ReadAccelerometer(Accelerometer accelerometer, out bool moveLeft, out bool moveRight)
    {
        AccelerometerReading accelerometerReading = accelerometer.CurrentValue;
        Vector3 acceleration = accelerometerReading.Acceleration;

        // establish the conditions to move left or right
    }
}
```